# Is there any limit for maximum number of TCP connections that can be made from a container to RabbitMQ

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, devops, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am new in rabbitmq, So i am facing a in rabbitmq like "The connection cannot support anymore channels.Consider creating a  new connection". So my doubt is can we create multiple tcp connections to rabbitmq from a single docker conatiner? Is there any limit for maximum number of TCP connections that can be made from a container? Please help

I tried to find out from doc but I didn't get a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we create multiple tcp connections to rabbitmq from a single docker container?

yes you can.

> Is there any limit for maximum number of TCP connections that can be made from a container?

There is no hard-coded limit. It depends on number of CPUs/Memory etc... RabbitMQ is not different from other kinds of services.

We have a [production checklist](https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html) with some best

> The connection cannot support anymore channels.Consider creating a new connection".

Adding too many channels inside one single connection is not recommended. There is no limit but hundreds of channels is not a good value.

Comment: Default is 128, max is 65535.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#:~:text=Default%20is%20128%2C%20max%20value%20is%2065535.

Comment: @VivekBani "Maximum number of remembered connection" not the max connections